# how to set the first lookAt/target of a Control

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need to set the initial 'lookAt' point of the scene, that will be the center of the screen and of the control's rotation.
If possible, I would prefer to set a point (or an object's position), not rotation angles.

The control is OrbitControl. If I simply set lookAt before the Control initialization, the center is restored to (0,0,0) on the first user interaction, which causes a 'gap' ...

```
// camera
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 20000);
camera.position.set(0,20,20);
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,10,0));

// controls
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );
```

How can I set the initial point in a proper way?

Comment: And for `@react-three/fiber` (drei) see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67950854/how-to-change-orbitcontrol-target-in-react

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try setting the control's target and remove the camera.lookAt call:

```js
controls.target = new THREE.Vector3(0, 10, 0);
controls.update();
```

Comment: Great! I had not realized that it could be done with this, works pefectly .. Thanks a lot

Comment: ...and then call `controls.update();` to get the first frame right.

Comment: This does not seem to work when you go to a different panorama and then come back to the new one, seems to be ignored. Any ideas?

Answer (score 15):

Or more directly (without instanciating a `new THREE.Vector3` but updating the values):

```js
controls.target.set(0, 10, 0);
```

NB: `controls.update()` [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20933125/how-to-set-the-first-lookat-target-of-a-control#comment64545531_20934235) still remains for the 1st frame